# AS3: Is there a way to programmatically get documentation comments from a class' method or property?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, documentation

I know that I can get info about constants, methods, etc of a class by using `flash.utils.describeType`. But I want to know if I can retrieve the asdoc comments of a class member.

I suspect, documentation is removed when classes are compiled into SWF so it might be impossible to get comments during run-time.. am I right?

Comment: I think you are right, at runtime, but you can do it before runtime from the source.

Comment: @nycynik Too old question. I don't code AS3 anymore. But I needed that so I can get doc/comments during runtime, I guess.

Comment: I'd like to hear what that 3 people have to say; who suggested to close this question bec. it's opinion-based (1) and too broad (2). This was a direct, specific, technical question and @JeffryHouser objectively answered.

Comment: I think they probably said that because your question can be answered in a lot of ways outside of flash.  So you can create documentation from code many ways.  It may be the case that you need to do it at runtime, but you probably do not, so this falls under code documentation methods, and there are many of them.

Comment: @nycynik the question was about "flash", "asdoc" and "SWF". All mentioned right within the post. Also see the tags. So it could not be answered in "a lot of ways".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this during runtime.  It is as you expected.  In the Flex Compiler comments are optimized out of the resulting SWF. This, in theory, helps decrease file size.  I assume Flash Pro does similar optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could generate your Asdoc comments beforehand (easy in FB4 if you google it), save them as an asset, and write a class to grap the doc comments based on the `flash.utils.describeType` properties as needed.